# Do filler episode characters ever appear in the main storyline?

Tags: naruto

Do any of the characters from the Naruto filler arcs or movies show up again in the main series, or they are just strictly made for the fillers and movies?

I was watching Shippuden season 1 and at some point the opening and closing songs had scenes from the Priestess Shion movie, or the first Naruto Shippuden movie.

Comment: They are just made for those filler/movies, but they do appear in the story as, something you can call, easter eggs. They also don't interact with the story nor characters. They are just there as extras.

Comment: @AkiraMahisaseru Oh. You are alive. Yay! . And okay. Thanks. Just wondering. So they do appear in the main shady occasionally right? Any examples?

Comment: I'm so sorry!!!! I lost my phone, but I finally found it!!! Please forgive me.

Comment: @AkiraMahisaseru Whoa... Take it easy, love. You are forgiven even though nothing held against you. Lol. I take you are fine then.  but anyway, examples of the extras?

Comment: You know that one lady that has cristal powers, that one kid that was with her, and that one big dude that liked her (I think), sorry I forgot their names, they appeared in one of the newer episodes (I forgot the number but it's before the Sasuke's story episodes)

Comment: @AkiraMahisaseru I believe you mean Guren (the lady) etc. they appeared in the crowd wanting to see naruto in episode 479.

Comment: Ahhh... Thanksss! I'll look her up!

Comment: @AkiraMahisaseru But guren appears in a main episode before continuing into filler episodes.. The main episode being 89. And the fillers being 90 onward..

Comment: @LabhanshAgrawal that's her name. Thank you for the episode number too. You understood what I meant.

Comment: @AkiraMahisaseru So would you count her as a filler character? Even though she may have appeared in canon episodes as well as filler episodes?

Comment: @Hansen but she's an anime only character

Comment: @LabhanshAgrawal I guess that makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @Hansen, I don't remember reading about her in the manga. She could have been there but I don't remember. I count her as a filler character since she didn't appear as an important character in  episodes later in the series.

Comment: @AkiraMahisaseru Oh. Alright. Thanks. I think she's an anime only character. Thanks again! Oh. I messaged you BTW so you can check it out when you can!

Comment: Didn't Naruto make a remark about Utakata (not sure about the name) in the anime, not the manga, after Tobi/Kabuto summoned the Edo-Tensei Jinchuuriki because of the filler in early Shippuuden.

Answer (score 1):

[Utakata](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Utakata) was introduced during [the so-named Tsuchigumo Kinjutsu arc](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/213/which-episodes-of-the-naruto-anime-are-core-plot-and-which-are-filler), but he eventually makes his way in the main storyline as a reanimated ninja fighting in the Great Shinobi War.

It could be conjectured that he wasn't a filler character, but until Naruto chapter 515 at the earliest, the Six-Tails host was not identified by name.

[image]

In this picture, Utakata is second from the left.