# Why does Naruto’s anime and manga have huge differences?

Tags: naruto

I started to watch Naruto and I didn’t read the manga. Some people told me that they have so many differences and its even like a separated version. Why is it like that? I searched it on Google but couldn’t find anything.

Comment: The only difference are the fillers. Anime has a lot, LOT, of fillers.

Comment: Related to the above comment: [Which episodes of the Naruto anime are core plot and which are filler?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/213), [Why make filler episodes?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/24283), [Why are there so many fillers in long-running animes?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/336), and their related questions (on the right sidebar)

Comment: @EroSɘnnin ohh i see

Comment: almost every anime will be a bit different from its manga in order to attract the manga readers cause if everything is exactly the same, there'd be no incentive for them.

Comment: The manga was ongoing when the anime was airing so they had to make a lot of fillers while waiting for new chapters

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are indeed some differences, but to call it a separated version? I think not.

In most anime, 1 episode tries to cover around 2-5 chapters of the manga. Quite often there is too much information or things going on in the chapters to properly cover in 1 episode of ~19 minutes. This means they have to 'cut down' some of the manga's content.
Cutting the content as such often leads to lacking some build up, or additional information. Which, especially if you did read the manga before, makes it feel like a whole different story. Or a lacking story.

Besides these differences, Naruto also features quite a few fillers. As [Aki Tanaka](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/2516/aki-tanaka) mentioned in the comments as well: [Which episodes of the Naruto anime are core plot and which are filler?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/213)

However, those fillers can be considered as additional content, as this does not *replace* content. But more about that is explained in [Why make filler episodes?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/24283)