# How come did Nagato's 6 path pains bodies died?

Tags: naruto

As far as I know, all the bodies of pain are corpses. How come it dies even if it is already dead. Also the chakra rods are not removed after they are killed. Meaning, it can still receive chakra and can fight.

Comment: Did you watched the episodes carefully? They explained the mechanism in one of the episodes.

Comment: No sir. I think I skipped it. sorry @FumikageTokoyami. Can you tell me what episode it is or can you explain the answer?

Comment: Where are you currently?  Which episode are you watching? It could be in one of the episodes during either the "Jiraiya infiltration arc" or the "Pain arc". I can't remember. Also, I'd suggest you to not skip episodes, at least not the episodes which has the main story. You can skip the fillers if you want. See [here](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/213/which-episodes-of-the-naruto-anime-are-core-plot-and-which-are-filler) for more details.

Comment: @Vince You can read more here: https://naruto.fandom.com/wiki/Nagato